How can I dynamically grow the number of threads in Spring Batch with a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` without rejecting incoming tasks?
I have a spring batch application that's in charge of a few dozen jobs which are running using cron scheduling.
I've been having some issues where some jobs aren't being ran, and I think this is because I was lacking a TaskExecutor, causing my JobLauncher to launch jobs synchronously.
I've included a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with the following bean configuration:
@Bean
fun taskExecutor(): TaskExecutor {
  val executor = ThreadPoolTaskExecutor()

  executor.corePoolSize = 1
  executor.maxPoolSize = 4
  executor.keepAliveSeconds = 600
  executor.queueCapacity = 1

  return executor
}

What I'm noticing here is that threads are created once the queue is greater than 1 task, up until 4 total threads -- after that, an exception is thrown and I can't add any more tasks to the queue (4 being processed and one in the queue).
I suppose this makes sense since I did set a queue capacity of 1, but my desired behavior is that an "infinite" number of tasks may be enqueued, with max 4 threads running until the number of available tasks to work on drops below my max.
Is there a way to do this with a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, or something similar?

I've closed this as a dup although I understand that ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is a wrapper around ThreadPoolExecutor.  Let me know if that's not appropriate and I'll reopen.

@Gray your answer in the other question does not answer this question.

Hrm ok.  I will unclose.

You can try with the following modifications:
@Bean
fun taskExecutor(): TaskExecutor {
    val executor = ThreadPoolTaskExecutor()

    executor.corePoolSize = 1
    executor.maxPoolSize = 4
    executor.keepAliveSeconds = 600
    executor.queueCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()) 

    return executor
}


Integer.MAX_VALUE ensures that the queue can hold as many tasks as needed without running into a size limit.

CallerRunsPolicy ensures that if all the threads are busy and the queue is full, the calling thread will run the task. It's handled by the calling thread instead of being rejected.



What happens if the caller is already running something?

Yeah, if the current task takes a long time to complete, Possibly it may cause a bottleneck.
You can use another rejection policy, like ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy, which will throw a RejectedExecutionException if tasks exceed the limit.

I think your answer is only ever going to have 1 thread running unless I exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE, which in practice is never going to happen? I still want items to be enqueued


... my desired behavior is that an "infinite" number of tasks may be enqueued, with max 4 threads

You should set your executor.queueCapacity to be Integer.MAX_VALUE  if you don't want the jobs to be rejected.  I would not use caller runs policy because that may block the reading of the jobs.
I really never use an unbounded queue because you can fill memory with the jobs depending on the queue add versus remove rate.  I would set the rejectedExecutionHandler to add the job to the queue so it will block when the queue is full.
See: How to get the ThreadPoolExecutor to increase threads to max before queueing?

running until the number of available tasks to work on drops below my max.

If you want the number of core threads to drop back down, I would enable core-thread timeout:
executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut = true;

You can set the keepAliveSeconds which determines how long before the core threads is reduced.  Unless you are starved for threads and the jobs are infrequent, I'm not sure how much you will save by doing this.
